# Increment an integer

Tags: abap

Sometimes ABAP drives me crazy with really simple tasks such as incrementing an integer within a loop...

Here's my try:

```
METHOD test.

  DATA lv_id TYPE integer.

  lv_id = 1.

  LOOP AT x ASSIGNING <y>.
    lv_id = lv_id+1.
  ENDLOOP.

ENDMETHOD.
```

This results in the error message **Field type "I" does not permit subfield access.**

Comment: maybe this works in new abap syntax: lv_id += 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You mean like:

```
ADD 1 to lv_id.
```

By the way, when you loop over an internal table, SY-TABIX has the loop counter.

Comment: Just beware of loops within loops. Oh, and if you are looping with a `DO..TIMES x`, then the loop counter will be `SY-INDEX`. Yes, ABAP is a terribly inconsistent language.

Comment: SY-TABIX does not contain the loop counter, it contains the table index. These are often different values. For instance, if I write `LOOP AT messages INTO msg WHERE type = 'E'`, the first time the loop actually runs might be on the fourth row, and the value of sy-tabix will be 4.

Answer (score 24):

You already answered the question yourself, but to make things a bit clearer:

```
variable + 1
```

is an arithmetic expression - add 1 to the value of the variable.

```
variable+1
```

is an offset operation on a character variable. For example, if variable contains `ABC`, `variable+1` is `BC`.

This can be especially confusing when dealing with NUMCs. For example, with `variable = '4711'`, `variable + 1` is evaluated to `4712`, whereas `variable+1` is `'711'` (a character sequence).

The error you saw occurred because it's not possible to perform the index operation on a non-character-like variable.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. I'm sure I don't make this mistake again ;)

Answer (score 8):

Uh, I got it.
It's the f****** spaces...

```
lv_id = lv_id + 1
```

works...

Comment: ...but if there is a more elegant way, I would be interested ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Simple**

DATA : gv_inc type I .

**place this statement in loop**

gv_inc = gv_inc + 1 .

Answer (score 1):

from SAP NetWeaver Version **7.54** you can also use:

```
lv_id += 1.
```

Instead of

```
lv_id = lv_id + 1.
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to increment every loop cycle than you can directly get the table size.

```
describe table x lines data(lv_id). "Out side of the loop.
```